# Excel Online/Sharepoint survey won't load

Tags: excel-services

[image]

At work we use a survey created through Excel Online/Office 365 to track issues our employees have with software. It's worked splendidly until a day or two ago when the survey just takes you to the loading screen but never loads. Survey still works well in IE, but I really don't want to force my employees to use IE instead of Firefox or Chrome. Admins can still access the backend of the form through FF/Chrome, but the survey won't load anymore for anyone.

Wasn't sure if this was a security thing or an issue that can be addressed by editing settings in about:config? I'm scrambling for answers to get this addressed ASAP but numerous searches on Google, Microsoft's help board and even here haven't helped. Hoping someone has some helpful input.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of what you're seeing? Are you getting any errors at all?

Comment: Yup, edited the original post. I blurred out the text as some of it is proprietary company info, however on the left you see Firefox which just loads and never pulls the survey and on the right is IE which loads the survey after about 3 to 5 seconds.

Comment: And you're having the same problem with Chrome?

Comment: Correct, same issue as FF where it just loads and loads and never brings up the survey. Because it worked in IE I was initially leaning towards it being a security setting somewhere in about:config that I could disable, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: I am also experiencing a similar problem. Some colleagues can access the survey form, while others cannot. When I try to edit the survey in Chrome of FF it does not load, while in IE it does. This survey has been working fine for 3-4 weeks with no complaints, but yesterday this changed. Apologies for not *answering* the question, just thought I'd chime in with similar issue and shared frustration. I will monitor this post for any updates and provide any related answers/insights I may receive.

Answer (score 1):

According to Microsoft Support...

"Several users have reported that they also have the same issue as you describe that the Excel surveys only work in IE at present but not working on other browsers. Given the situation, I suggest you using IE to open the surveys as a workaround for the time being."

http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/172/t/292295.aspx